# Ruby On Rails - DB Structure for saving CRUD operation parameter/payload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, schema

## What I want

I want to make a form to save "CRUD operation Infomation itself" in my database.

e.g.)
①`create new row {"name": "Tom", "price": 200}`
②`find a row WHERE {"age": 30}`
③`delete row WHERE {"name": "John"}`
④`update the row WHERE {"name": "Ted"} SET {"price": 300}`

## My idea

To realize above, I created two models.

```
①CrudOperation  
t.string :crud_type # this should be one of CRUD ("create", "read", "update", "delete")  
t.string :target_database   



②CrudOperationParameter  
t.integer :crud_operation_id # reference  
t.string :key  
t.value :value
```

CrudOperation has many CrudOperationParameter-s.

## Problem

My models seem to work well EXCEPT crud_type is "update".

like that

①create new row {"name": "Tom", "price": 200}

```
**CrudOperation**  
id: 1  
crud_type: "create"  
target_database: "XXXX"  

**CrudOperationParameter**  
crud_operation_id: 1  
key: "name"  
value "Tom"  

**Another CrudOperationParameter**  
crud_operation_id: 1  
key: "price"  
value "200"
```

But when it comes to registering the CrudOperation with update type, the problem occurs.

④update the row WHERE {"name": "Ted"} SET {"price": 300}

```
**CrudOperation**  
id: 1  
crud_type: "update"  
target_database: "XXXX"  

**CrudOperationParameter**  
crud_operation_id: 1  
key: "name"  
value "Ted"  

**Another CrudOperationParameter**  
crud_operation_id: 1  
key: "price"  
value "300"
```

Since CrudOperationParameter has only key-value column,
I cannot identify that this CrudOperationParameter is for WHERE clause or SET clause in UPDATE Statement.

Could you teach me better DB schema to save these kinds of data?

Answer (score 1):

What you have is basically a half-baked version of the [Entity Attribute Value pattern](https://inviqa.com/blog/understanding-eav-data-model-and-when-use-it#:%7E:text=Entity%2DAttribute%2DValue%20design%20is,the%20facts%20that%20it%20describes.) (or anti-pattern depending on who you are asking).

If I really had to I would set it up as:

```
class CrudOperation < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :crud_operation_parameters
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :crud_operation_parameters
  enum crud_type: {
    create: "create",
    read: "read", 
    update: "update",
    delete: "delete"
  }

  # Convenience setter that maps a hash of attributes 
  # into a an array of key value attibutes suitible for `accepts_nested_attributes_for`
  # and sets the nested attributes
  # @return [Array]
  def parameters=(hash)
    self.crud_operation_parameters_attributes = hash.map do |key, value|
       {
         key: key,
         value: value
       }
    end
  end
end
```

```
class CrudOperationParameter < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :crud_operation
end
```

```
# 1. create new row {"name": "Tom", "price": 200}
CrudOperation.create!(
  crud_type: :create,
  parameters: { 
    name: "Tom", 
    price: 200
  }
)

# 1. create new row {"name": "Tom", "price": 200}
CrudOperation.create!(
  crud_type: :update,
  parameters: { 
    name: "Tom", 
    price: 200
  }
)
```

I mentioned that its a half baked attempt since you're lacking the Attribute table where you would normalize the definitions of attributes and store stuff like type information. Your solution instead has a string column with tons of duplicates that can become denormalized.

But modern RDBMS systems have column types such as JSON, JSONB and HSTORE which can be used instead of EAV to store data which does not fit a given schema.

Unlike EAV you don't have to store all the attributes in a single column type (usually a string) and typecast or create a bunch of attribute tables to store different types of attributes (such as StringCrudOperationParameter and FloatCrudOperationParameter).

With JSONB on Postgres I would set it up as:

```
# rails g model crud_operation crud_type:string payload:jsonb conditions:jsonb
class CrudOperation < ApplicationRecord
  enum crud_type: {
    create: "create",
    read: "read", 
    update: "update",
    delete: "delete"
  }
end
```

```
# 1. create new row {"name": "Tom", "price": 200}
CrudOperation.create!(
  crud_type: :create,
  payload: {
    name: "Tom", 
    price: 200
  }
)

# 2. find a row WHERE {"age": 30}
CrudOperation.create!(
  crud_type: :read,
  conditions: {
    age: 30
  }
)

# 3. delete row WHERE {"name": "John"}
CrudOperation.create!(
  crud_type: :delete,
  conditions: {
    name: "John"
  }
)

# 4. update the row WHERE {"name": "Ted"} SET {"price": 300}
CrudOperation.create!(
  crud_type: :update,
  conditions: {
    name: "John"
  },
  payload: {
    price: 300
  }
)
```

Comment: Thank you for your support! Your CrudOperationParameter has two associations: 
crud_operation and crud_operation_attribute.Can you please tell me what the role of "crud_operation_attribute" is?

Comment: Ah sorry I actually meant to remove it. I was planning on adding an attribute table initially but simplefyied the example. If you had an attribute normalization table thats what you would use instead of having storing a bunch of strings in the `key` table. If you check out the link https://inviqa.com/blog/understanding-eav-data-model-and-when-use-it#:%7E:text=Entity%2DAttribute%2DValue%20design%20is,the%20facts%20that%20it%20describes they have some pretty good diagrams of the EAV table setup that explains it.

Comment: Basically by storing a foreign key you avoid some of the issues with denormalization like for example having rows with `colour` and `color` and can use a more efficient index at the cost of an additional join.

Comment: I really apreciate your great comment! I read article you posted. In my case, I would never call a query like `CrudOperation.crud_operation_attributes(name: "attribute_name")` because CrudOperation will be used to call CRUD API outside my app. How about this case?

Comment: Whats the purpose here? Do you just need to keep track of the calls to the API for auditing and and the data won't be modified after creation?

Comment: I would probally either use two JSONB columns (conditions and payload) or just store the entire body sent to the API if its a JSON API along with the URI.

Comment: I edited the answer. If you wanted to do the same thing with EAV you would need two different value tables or a "type" column that tells you if its an condition or the payload. Sounds like a messy PITA.

Comment: Thank you so much. To save column as JSON seems better choice...I will reconsider my model structure.